# Random integer / occurrences (C++) issues

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, random, for-loop

I've been currently stuck on a C++ problem for about an hour and half. Here's the question:

Write a program that generates one hundred random integers between 0 and 9 and displays the count for each number. (Hint: Use rand() 
% 10 to generate a random integer between 0 and 9. Use an array of ten integers, 
say counts, to store the counts for the number of O's, l 's, . .. , 9's.)

And here's what I have so far. I think I'm pretty close, but I keep on getting "0" for the occurrences (or counts) of each random integer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const int SIZE = 100;

int main()
{
int integers[SIZE];
int index;
int zero = 0;
int one = 0;
int two = 0;
int three = 0;
int four = 0;
int five = 0;
int six = 0;
int seven = 0;
int eight = 0;
int nine = 0;

cout << "The following 100 integers are random:" << endl;
cout << endl;

srand(time(0));

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    integers[SIZE] = rand() % 10;
    cout << integers[SIZE] << " ";
}

cout << endl;

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 0)
    {
        zero += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 1)
    {
        one += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 2)
    {
        two += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 3)
    {
        three += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 4)
    {
        four += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 5)
    {
        five += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 6)
    {
        six += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 7)
    {
        seven += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 8)
    {
        eight += 1;
    }
}

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    if (integers[index] == 9)
    {
        nine += 1;
    }
}

cout << "The number of zeros in the random list are " << zero << endl;
cout << "The number of ones in the random list are " << one << endl;
cout << "The number of twos in the random list are " << two << endl;
cout << "The number of threes in the random list are " << three << endl;
cout << "The number of fours in the random list are " << four << endl;
cout << "The number of fives in the random list are " << five << endl;
cout << "The number of sixes in the random list are " << six << endl;
cout << "The number of sevens in the random list are " << seven << endl;
cout << "The number of eights in the random list are " << eight << endl;
cout << "The number of nines in the random list are " << nine << endl;

getch();

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour because you're using `SIZE` as the index to your array instead of `index`:

```
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    integers[SIZE] = rand() % 10;
    cout << integers[SIZE] << " ";
}
```

This will access outside the bounds of the array (since the range is from `0` to `SIZE-1`). Inside the body of the loop, change `SIZE` to `index`.

However, I think it would help you to reread your problem statement. Specifically:

> Use an array of ten integers, say `counts`, to store the counts for the number of 0s, 1s, ... , 9s

You are instead using an array to store your random numbers. This is not necessary at all. You do not need to keep track of the generated numbers. You just need to add 1 to the appropriate count and then you can simply discard the random number.

You should simply have an array called `counts`, where `counts[0]` stores the number of `0`s so far, `counts[1]` stores the number of `1`s, etc. Then you don't need these horrible variables called `zero`, `one`, `two`, and so on. If you ever find yourself defining variable names like that (with increasing numbers in them), then you should probably be using an array instead.

Comment: Thanks, this helped quite a bit

Comment: @jtarr523 Just remember, whenever you start copying the same code over and over, you should probably rethink what you're doing.